# Youtube Signature issue with some videos

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

When I'm trying to generate video download URL from localhost with PHP, it's working perfectly creating signature automatically with all videos. But when I'm shipping my code to server trying to generate download URL (for same video), it's not giving Signature with same video. Why it's happening? If the video can create signature on localhost why not on server? What actually is the wrong thing? I'm just kinda stuck.

```
$id = $_GET['id']; //The youtube video ID

parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$id.'&sts=&asv=3&el=detailpage'),$info); 
$streams = explode(',',$info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map']); 
parse_str($streams[0], $str);

echo $str['url'];
```

Comment: Please show us some code, this is a coding site and we cant really help without something to look at.

Comment: I know but there's nothing to show i think. If you passed that then you know what i'm talking and how to take care on that but if you don't then you will won't understand..